# remove a text following an @ symbol in jquery

Tags: jquery

what is the most easiest approach in jquery to remove a particular `string` or `word` inside an html paragraph.

I'm using twitter API callback `['text']` to retrieve **mention_timelines** (https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/mentions_timeline.json)
 from a twitter account.

the text output of `['text']` is `@john lets have lunch!` this is what i retrieve

how can i remove the `@john` or all texts following the `@` symbol in jquery? so i'd only have to get `lets have lunch!`

Comment: You can't. jQuery has no such feature. [Vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com) has many useful string functions like `newStr = oldStr.replace(/@\S+\s/g,'');`

Answer (score 0):

Use regexp.

```
['text'].replace(/@[a-z0-9]+/,'')
```

Comment: do i just place this inside my `<script>`? sorry for this ignorant question.

Comment: replace() is a string function, it shoud be something like this: var s = 'something something'; s.replace(/regexp/,'substritution'); in <script>, near a function that retrieve stuff.

Answer (score 0):

```
var splittedTest = text.split(' ');
var newText = '';
for(var i = 0 i < splittedTest.length;i++)
{
   if(splittedTest[i].indexOf("@") == -1)
   {
      newText += splittedTest[i] + " "
   }
}
```

Should work